# Where is my .profile file in Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac-osx, java, mac

I am setting up Apache Tomcat on my OS X 10.6.2 and need to know where my .profile file is, for setting environment variables. I thought it was in the root of my home directory, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 3):

The `.profile` file isn't created by default.

To set the environment variables make a file called `.profile` in the root of your home directory (`/Users/<yourshortname>/` or `~/` for short) and put the necessary variables in it.  Tomcat will find it automatically based on the name.

Answer (score 2):

Users don't get a profile by default -- they use the systemwide shell at /etc/profile.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be created, but should source successfully if you create a new file at `~/.profile`. Try a simple `alias` or something similar and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Old but still relevant: [bash on Mac OS X - O'Reilly Media](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2004/02/24/bash.html)